# Why can't I get parameters from launch file?

Tags: ros2, ros2-launch

my system_initialize exe source code：

```
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "device_interface/DeviceDriver/device_timer.h"
#include "device_interface/Base/RobotSystem.h"

class InitializerNode : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
    InitializerNode() : Node("initializer_node")
    {
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Initializer node is starting up...");
        std::string system_arg;
        if (this->get_parameter("system_arg", system_arg))
        {
            RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Parameter \"system_arg\" is %s ", system_arg.c_str());
        }else{
            RCLCPP_ERROR(this->get_logger(), "Parameter \"system_arg\" not find");
        }

        HYYRobotBase::command_arg arg;
        if (0 == HYYRobotBase::commandLineParser1(system_arg.c_str(), &arg)){
            if (0 != HYYRobotBase::system_initialize(&arg)){
                RCLCPP_ERROR(this->get_logger(), "device initialize failure! system_initialize faiure!");
            }
        }else{
            RCLCPP_ERROR(this->get_logger(), "device initialize failure! commandLineParser1 faiure!");
        }
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Initialization complete, node exiting.");
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    auto node = std::make_shared<InitializerNode>();
    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

my xmate_hardware_driver exe source code：

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include "controller_manager/controller_manager.hpp"
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "realtime_tools/thread_priority.hpp"

#include "device_interface/DeviceDriver/device_timer.h"
#include "device_interface/Base/RobotSystem.h"

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

namespace
{
// Reference: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setparam.2.html
// This value is used when configuring the main loop to use SCHED_FIFO scheduling
// We use a midpoint RT priority to allow maximum flexibility to users
int const kSchedPriority = 50;

}  // namespace

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  int communication_time = 0;
  std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Executor> executor = std::make_shared<rclcpp::executors::MultiThreadedExecutor>();

  std::string manager_node_name = "controller_manager";
  auto cm = std::make_shared<controller_manager::ControllerManager>(executor, manager_node_name);

  RCLCPP_INFO(cm->get_logger(), "start ros2 robot.");
  if (cm->get_parameter("communication_time", communication_time)){
    RCLCPP_INFO(cm->get_logger(), "Parameter \"communication_time\" is %d ", communication_time);
  }else{
    RCLCPP_ERROR(cm->get_logger(), "Parameter \"communication_time\" not find");
  }
  if (0 != HYYRobotBase::initPriority(38)){
    RCLCPP_ERROR(cm->get_logger(), "program priority set failure!");
    return 0;
  }

  RCLCPP_INFO(cm->get_logger(), "update rate is %d Hz", cm->get_update_rate());

  std::thread cm_thread(
    [cm, communication_time]()
    {
      if (realtime_tools::has_realtime_kernel()){
        if (!realtime_tools::configure_sched_fifo(kSchedPriority)){
          RCLCPP_WARN(cm->get_logger(), "Could not enable FIFO RT scheduling policy");
        }
      }else{
        RCLCPP_INFO(cm->get_logger(), "RT kernel is recommended for better performance");
      }

      // initial timer
      HYYRobotBase::RTimer timer;
      if (0 != HYYRobotBase::initUserTimer(&timer, 0, 1)){
        RCLCPP_ERROR(cm->get_logger(), "device_timer start failure!");
      }

      // set loop time.
      rclcpp::Duration d_time(0, communication_time);

      // loop initial time.
      rclcpp::Time curtime = cm->now();

      //
      struct timeval start, end;
      int __dtime = 0;

      while (rclcpp::ok())
      {

        //
        gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

        // Timing.
        HYYRobotBase::userTimer(&timer);

        // execute update loop.
        cm->read(curtime, d_time);
        cm->update(curtime, d_time);
        cm->write(curtime, d_time);
        curtime += d_time;

        //
        gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
        __dtime = (end.tv_sec * 1000000 + end.tv_usec) - (start.tv_sec * 1000000 + start.tv_usec);
        if (__dtime > (communication_time / 1000 * 0.8)){
          RCLCPP_ERROR(cm->get_logger(), "Over time: loop time is %d us", __dtime);
        }
      }
    }
  );

  executor->add_node(cm);
  executor->spin();
  cm_thread.join();
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

my launch file：

```
declared_arguments.append(
    DeclareLaunchArgument(
        "system_arg",
        default_value="--path /home/robot/Work/system/robot_config --iscopy true",
        description="args for system initialize ",
    )
)
system_arg = LaunchConfiguration("system_arg")
system_intialize_node = Node(
    package="xmate_hardware_driver",
    executable="system_initialize",
    output="both",
    parameters=[{'system_arg':system_arg}]
)
control_node = Node(
    package="xmate_hardware_driver",
    executable="xmate_hardware_driver",
    output="both",
    parameters=[
                # {'system_arg':system_arg},
                {'communication_time':communication_time},
                robot_description,
                robot_controllers
                ]
)
```

my output：

```
robotck@robotckvrm:~/ros2_ws$ ros2 launch xmate_hardware_driver xmate_driver.launch.py 
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/robotck/.ros/log/2024-03-26-18-00-47-266658-robotckvrm-12669
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [system_initialize-1]: process started with pid [12671]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-2]: process started with pid [12673]
[system_initialize-1] [INFO] [1711447247.647437902] [initializer_node]: Initializer node is starting up...
[system_initialize-1] [ERROR] [1711447247.647536098] [initializer_node]: **Parameter "system_arg" not find**
[system_initialize-1] sched_setscheduler() failed: Operation not permitted
[system_initialize-1] [ERROR] [1711447247.647595854] [initializer_node]: device initialize failure! system_initialize faiure!
[system_initialize-1] [INFO] [1711447247.647603384] [initializer_node]: Initialization complete, node exiting.
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1711447247.660861086] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_footprint
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1711447247.660992392] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1711447247.661003487] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link1
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1711447247.661009413] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link2
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1711447247.661014498] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link3
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1711447247.661019415] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link4
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1711447247.661024169] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link5
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1711447247.661028850] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link6
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1711447247.661033670] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link7
```

Comment: This is not related to ros2_control, because your initializer_node already can't get the parameters. Which ROS distro are you using?

Comment: i use ros2 humble， i override the ros2_control_node, and add some self-define paramaters to the code ,if i get paramater from cm->get_parameter(), it works, but if i want to get parameter before control manager Instantiate,  it goes wrong like what i put up. why??

Comment: I separated the code for getting system_arg into a new executable file called system_initialize. I started system_initialize first and then started xmate_hardware_driver

Comment: I don't understand why you have to use a different design pattern than the usual ros2_control one. However, your node already seems to have problems to load the parameter before ros2_control comes into play. Check with tools like rqt_reconfigure if the parameter is really set. Humble should not have problems with undeclared parameters afaik, but try declare your parameter before getting it.

Comment: you mean use declare_param（） first？although i have declared it in launch file？now, I move the system initialization part to the hardware interface file and get the parameters from urdf. have accomplished.