# ros2 node/param list shows no infomation, ros2 topic/action/service list shows infoamation, why? what is wrong?

Tags: ros2, ros2-control, dds, ros2-controllers

here is the log info:

```
root@robot:/home/robot/ros2_ws# ros2 launch xmate_hardware_driver xmate_driver.launch.py 
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /root/.ros/log/2024-03-27-21-54-28-112041-robot-3943
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [xmate_hardware_driver-1]: process started with pid [3946]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-2]: process started with pid [3948]
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1711590868.826303087] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_footprint
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1711590868.827350028] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1711590868.827970541] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link1
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1711590868.828547429] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link2
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [WARN] [1711590868.828783981] [controller_manager]: [Deprecated] Passing the robot description parameter directly to the control_manager node is deprecated. Use '~/robot_description' topic from 'robot_state_publisher' instead.
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [INFO] [1711590868.829322060] [resource_manager]: Loading hardware 'xmate_ros2_control' 
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1711590868.830017702] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link3
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1711590868.830556697] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link4
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1711590868.831265050] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link5
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1711590868.832798114] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link6
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1711590868.833436085] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link7
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [INFO] [1711590868.848872756] [resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'xmate_ros2_control' 
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [INFO] [1711590868.850308499] [XmateHardwareDriver]: parammeter "system_arg" = --path /home/robot/Work/system/robot_config --iscopy true
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [INFO] [1711590868.856812681] [XmateHardwareDriver]: robot name: ec_device1/robot0.
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [INFO] [1711590868.856865055] [XmateHardwareDriver]: robot index: 0.
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [INFO] [1711590868.856878392] [XmateHardwareDriver]: robot joint num = 7.
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [INFO] [1711590868.856995578] [XmateHardwareDriver]: parammeter "sim_flag" = False.
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [INFO] [1711590868.857026362] [XmateHardwareDriver]: parammeter "device_mode" = 8
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [INFO] [1711590868.857055620] [XmateHardwareDriver]: robot run mode is set to 8
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [INFO] [1711590868.857163257] [resource_manager]: Successful initialization of hardware 'xmate_ros2_control'
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [INFO] [1711590868.857174956] [XmateHardwareDriver]: exporting state interfaces
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [INFO] [1711590868.857317990] [XmateHardwareDriver]: exporting command interfaces
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [INFO] [1711590868.857511704] [resource_manager]: 'configure' hardware 'xmate_ros2_control' 
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [INFO] [1711590868.857525373] [resource_manager]: Successful 'configure' of hardware 'xmate_ros2_control'
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [INFO] [1711590868.857541965] [resource_manager]: 'activate' hardware 'xmate_ros2_control' 
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [INFO] [1711590868.908322722] [resource_manager]: Successful 'activate' of hardware 'xmate_ros2_control'
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [INFO] [1711590868.914478848] [controller_manager]: start ros2 robot.
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [INFO] [1711590868.914534420] [controller_manager]: Parameter "communication_time" is 1000000 ns
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [INFO] [1711590868.914555415] [controller_manager]: update rate is 1000 Hz
[INFO] [spawner-3]: process started with pid [3978]
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [INFO] [1711590872.626166517] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[spawner-3] [INFO] [1711590872.636736067] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Loaded joint_state_broadcaster
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [INFO] [1711590872.638658090] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [INFO] [1711590872.638823773] [joint_state_broadcaster]: 'joints' or 'interfaces' parameter is empty. All available state interfaces will be published
[spawner-3] [INFO] [1711590872.655413412] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Configured and activated joint_state_broadcaster
[INFO] [spawner-3]: process has finished cleanly [pid 3978]
[INFO] [spawner-4]: process started with pid [3991]
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [INFO] [1711590876.578484991] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'arm_controller'
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [WARN] [1711590876.592562160] [arm_controller]: [Deprecated]: "allow_nonzero_velocity_at_trajectory_end" is set to true. The default behavior will change to false.
[spawner-4] [INFO] [1711590876.602588801] [spawner_arm_controller]: Loaded arm_controller
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [INFO] [1711590876.606023421] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'arm_controller'
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [INFO] [1711590876.606344672] [arm_controller]: No specific joint names are used for command interfaces. Using 'joints' parameter.
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [INFO] [1711590876.606387469] [arm_controller]: Command interfaces are [position velocity] and state interfaces are [position velocity].
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [INFO] [1711590876.606406104] [arm_controller]: Using 'splines' interpolation method.
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [INFO] [1711590876.607468826] [arm_controller]: Controller state will be published at 50.00 Hz.
[xmate_hardware_driver-1] [INFO] [1711590876.609146944] [arm_controller]: Action status changes will be monitored at 20.00 Hz.
[spawner-4] [INFO] [1711590876.626619498] [spawner_arm_controller]: Configured and activated arm_controller
[INFO] [spawner-4]: process has finished cleanly [pid 3991]
```

i use cli

```
ros2 node/param/topic/action/service list
```

it shows:

```
robot@robot:~$ ros2 node list 
robot@robot:~$ ros2 topic list 
/XmateHardwareDriver/transition_event
/arm_controller/controller_state
/arm_controller/joint_trajectory
/arm_controller/state
/arm_controller/transition_event
/dynamic_joint_states
/joint_state_broadcaster/transition_event
/joint_states
/parameter_events
/robot_description
/rosout
/tf
/tf_static
robot@robot:~$ ros2 param list 
robot@robot:~$ ros2 service list 
/XmateHardwareDriver/change_state
/XmateHardwareDriver/describe_parameters
/XmateHardwareDriver/get_available_states
/XmateHardwareDriver/get_available_transitions
/XmateHardwareDriver/get_parameter_types
/XmateHardwareDriver/get_parameters
/XmateHardwareDriver/get_state
/XmateHardwareDriver/get_transition_graph
/XmateHardwareDriver/list_parameters
/XmateHardwareDriver/set_parameters
/XmateHardwareDriver/set_parameters_atomically
/arm_controller/describe_parameters
/arm_controller/get_parameter_types
/arm_controller/get_parameters
/arm_controller/list_parameters
/arm_controller/query_state
/arm_controller/set_parameters
/arm_controller/set_parameters_atomically
/controller_manager/configure_controller
/controller_manager/describe_parameters
/controller_manager/get_parameter_types
/controller_manager/get_parameters
/controller_manager/list_controller_types
/controller_manager/list_controllers
/controller_manager/list_hardware_components
/controller_manager/list_hardware_interfaces
/controller_manager/list_parameters
/controller_manager/load_controller
/controller_manager/reload_controller_libraries
/controller_manager/set_hardware_component_state
/controller_manager/set_parameters
/controller_manager/set_parameters_atomically
/controller_manager/switch_controller
/controller_manager/unload_controller
/joint_state_broadcaster/describe_parameters
/joint_state_broadcaster/get_parameter_types
/joint_state_broadcaster/get_parameters
/joint_state_broadcaster/list_parameters
/joint_state_broadcaster/set_parameters
/joint_state_broadcaster/set_parameters_atomically
/robot_state_publisher/describe_parameters
/robot_state_publisher/get_parameter_types
/robot_state_publisher/get_parameters
/robot_state_publisher/list_parameters
/robot_state_publisher/set_parameters
/robot_state_publisher/set_parameters_atomically
robot@robot:~$ ros2 action  list 
/arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory
```

why there are no nodes? no params? i use

```
top
```

find xmate_hardware_driver and robot_state_publisher process exist.
On the basis of the previous one, I connected to the Internet, i run docker，

```
ros2 node list
```

recovered
docker report shows:

```
   NETWORK CONFIGURATION
inet         : 127.0.0.1
inet4        : ['127.0.0.1']
inet6        : ['::1']
netmask      : 255.0.0.0
device       : lo
flags        : 73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>
mtu          : 65536
inet         : 192.168.0.99
inet4        : ['192.168.0.99']
ether        : 68:ed:a4:6f:40:7e
inet6        : ['fe80::6aed:a4ff:fe6f:407e%enp1s0']
netmask      : 255.255.255.0
device       : enp1s0
flags        : 4163<UP,MULTICAST,RUNNING,BROADCAST>
mtu          : 1500
broadcast    : 192.168.0.255
inet         : 192.168.1.112
inet4        : ['192.168.1.112']
ether        : 00:13:ef:3f:25:c8
inet6        : ['fe80::7f2c:52da:736e:2d97%wlx0013ef3f25c8']
netmask      : 255.255.255.0
device       : wlx0013ef3f25c8
flags        : 4163<UP,MULTICAST,RUNNING,BROADCAST>
mtu          : 1500
broadcast    : 192.168.1.255
ether        : 68:ed:a4:6d:6e:a9
device       : eno1
flags        : 4099<UP,MULTICAST,BROADCAST>
mtu          : 1500
ether        : 68:ed:a4:6d:6e:aa
device       : enp3s0
flags        : 4099<UP,MULTICAST,BROADCAST>
mtu          : 1500

   PACKAGE VERSIONS
xmate_hardware_driver                     : latest=, local=0.0.0
xmate_hardware_interface                  : latest=, local=0.0.0
xmate_description                         : latest=, local=0.0.0
      ...                                         ...

   PLATFORM INFORMATION
system           : Linux
platform info    : Linux-5.15.113-rt64-x86_64-with-glibc2.35
release          : 5.15.113-rt64
processor        : x86_64

   QOS COMPATIBILITY LIST
topic [type]            : /joint_states [sensor_msgs/msg/JointState]
publisher node          : joint_state_broadcaster
subscriber node         : robot_state_publisher
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : controller_manager
subscriber node         : controller_manager
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : controller_manager
subscriber node         : XmateHardwareDriver
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : controller_manager
subscriber node         : joint_state_broadcaster
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : controller_manager
subscriber node         : arm_controller
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : controller_manager
subscriber node         : robot_state_publisher
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : controller_manager
subscriber node         : robot_state_publisher
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : XmateHardwareDriver
subscriber node         : controller_manager
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : XmateHardwareDriver
subscriber node         : XmateHardwareDriver
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : XmateHardwareDriver
subscriber node         : joint_state_broadcaster
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : XmateHardwareDriver
subscriber node         : arm_controller
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : XmateHardwareDriver
subscriber node         : robot_state_publisher
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : XmateHardwareDriver
subscriber node         : robot_state_publisher
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : joint_state_broadcaster
subscriber node         : controller_manager
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : joint_state_broadcaster
subscriber node         : XmateHardwareDriver
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : joint_state_broadcaster
subscriber node         : joint_state_broadcaster
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : joint_state_broadcaster
subscriber node         : arm_controller
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : joint_state_broadcaster
subscriber node         : robot_state_publisher
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : joint_state_broadcaster
subscriber node         : robot_state_publisher
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : arm_controller
subscriber node         : controller_manager
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : arm_controller
subscriber node         : XmateHardwareDriver
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : arm_controller
subscriber node         : joint_state_broadcaster
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : arm_controller
subscriber node         : arm_controller
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : arm_controller
subscriber node         : robot_state_publisher
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : arm_controller
subscriber node         : robot_state_publisher
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : robot_state_publisher
subscriber node         : controller_manager
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : robot_state_publisher
subscriber node         : XmateHardwareDriver
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : robot_state_publisher
subscriber node         : joint_state_broadcaster
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : robot_state_publisher
subscriber node         : arm_controller
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : robot_state_publisher
subscriber node         : robot_state_publisher
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : robot_state_publisher
subscriber node         : robot_state_publisher
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : _ros2cli_daemon_0_da1c73573f07410eb166df1eaad13921
subscriber node         : controller_manager
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : _ros2cli_daemon_0_da1c73573f07410eb166df1eaad13921
subscriber node         : XmateHardwareDriver
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : _ros2cli_daemon_0_da1c73573f07410eb166df1eaad13921
subscriber node         : joint_state_broadcaster
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : _ros2cli_daemon_0_da1c73573f07410eb166df1eaad13921
subscriber node         : arm_controller
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : _ros2cli_daemon_0_da1c73573f07410eb166df1eaad13921
subscriber node         : robot_state_publisher
compatibility status    : OK
topic [type]            : /parameter_events [rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent]
publisher node          : _ros2cli_daemon_0_da1c73573f07410eb166df1eaad13921
subscriber node         : robot_state_publisher
compatibility status    : OK

   RMW MIDDLEWARE
middleware name    : rmw_fastrtps_cpp

   ROS 2 INFORMATION
distribution name      : humble
distribution type      : ros2
distribution status    : active
release platforms      : {'debian': ['bullseye'], 'rhel': ['8'], 'ubuntu': ['jammy']}

   TOPIC LIST
topic               : /XmateHardwareDriver/transition_event
publisher count     : 0
subscriber count    : 0
topic               : /arm_controller/controller_state
publisher count     : 0
subscriber count    : 0
topic               : /arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/_action/feedback
publisher count     : 0
subscriber count    : 0
topic               : /arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/_action/status
publisher count     : 0
subscriber count    : 0
topic               : /arm_controller/joint_trajectory
publisher count     : 0
subscriber count    : 0
topic               : /arm_controller/state
publisher count     : 0
subscriber count    : 0
topic               : /arm_controller/transition_event
publisher count     : 0
subscriber count    : 0
topic               : /dynamic_joint_states
publisher count     : 0
subscriber count    : 0
topic               : /joint_state_broadcaster/transition_event
publisher count     : 0
subscriber count    : 0
topic               : /joint_states
publisher count     : 0
subscriber count    : 0
topic               : /robot_description
publisher count     : 0
subscriber count    : 0
topic               : /tf
publisher count     : 0
subscriber count    : 0
topic               : /tf_static
publisher count     : 0
subscriber count    : 0
```

if i turn off network，publisher node and subscriber node are UNKNOW in  QOS COMPATIBILITY LIST , why??????
now i still can not echo topic like:

```
ros2 topic echo /robot_decription
```

,nothing shows.....why ????

Comment: my xmate_hardware_driver exe source code and part launch code can refer to my previous question“https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/110248/why-cant-i-get-parameters-from-launch-file”。

Comment: Please add information about your ROS distro and RMW implementation that you use.

Comment: i have update the issue, and make some progress。